# Post data don't send using jQuery Ajax request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

how to send large `base64` data Array using jQuery Ajax. Here is my code :

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "addPhoto.php",                                
        data:{photosArray:photosArray},
        dataType: "json",           
        success: function(data) {                   
                 $(data).each(function(){
                     ...
                 });
        }           
});
```

`photosArray` contains between 3 and 12 very long strings like :

`data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABQAAAAUCAMAAAC6V+0...`

Is there any limit for POST data size in Ajax?

Comment: Do you mean the request is sent and your server scripts do not see anything, or that the request is never made? If the former look at your server settings, some software limits the upload post size, for instance php has `post_max_size` and `upload_max_filesize`.

Answer (score 0):

Open your php.ini file and find the line stating upload_max_filesize. The default it set to 2M, which is 2MB. Try increasing it to 3MB and see if you are still receiving the error.
And use

```
      "cache": false
```

Comment: @Vivien Neault, You should upvote for the right answer. It might be helpful for others who are facing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Is your data properly declared ? It can be either String, object or array. try following

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
    url: "addPhoto.php",                                
    data:"{photosArray:photosArray}",
    dataType: "json",           
    success: function(data) {                   
             $(data).each(function(){
                 ...
             });
    }      
});
```

Comment: Thanks , it works. The problem was post_max_size and upload_max_filesize in php.ini !